# Stream symmetric encrypted data with java that can be decryptet by GPG

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, gnupg

I am trying to stream output a large file that can be decrypted with the following command:

`gpg --decrypt --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase="password"`

I do not know the size of the data before I start streaming.

I am able to encrypt using Java Cipher, but it appears then that it can only be decrypted using OpenSSL.

I have looked into Bouncy Castle and BouncyGPG but find it hard to find good examples using symmetric encryption and a passphrase only. I am able to encrypt using GPG and a passphrase in both ends, so I feel that it should be possible when encrypting with Java too.

The closest example I've found is https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/PBEFileProcessor.java

I have tried to adjust this example so that I can pass through a stream in a similar way to Java Cipher, but I've been unable to get it working, and I don't even know if I am on the right path.

UPDATE:

I got it to work now. Below is the code used:

```
    public OutputStream cOut;

    public OutputStream armoredOutputStream;

    public OutputStream encryptedOutputStream;

    public PGPEncrypter() {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public OutputStream encrypt(
        OutputStream encryptedOutputStream, String passPhrase
    ) throws IOException,
        PGPException {

        encryptedOutputStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(encryptedOutputStream);

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
            new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.AES_256)
                .setWithIntegrityPacket(true)
                .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setProvider("BC"));

        encGen.addMethod(new JcePBEKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(passPhrase.toCharArray()).setProvider("BC"));

        OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(encryptedOutputStream, new byte[4096]);

        PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        return lData.open(cOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, "", new Date(), new byte[4096]);
    }
```

Testing it with:

```
PGPEncrypter pgpEncrypter = new PGPEncrypter();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("encrypted.txt");
OutputStream outputStream = pgpEncrypter.encrypt(fileOutputStream, "password");
outputStream.write("content".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
outputStream.close()
pgpEncrypter.cOut.close()
pgpEncrypter.armoredOutputStream.close()
pgpEncrypter.encryptedOutputStream.close()
```

And then I am able to decrypt using PGP and the command at the start of the post.

The next step will be to have the class extend OutputStream and automatically close the underlying streams in the correct order when `close()` is called.

Comment: It would help if you showed off what you have so far. A crucial piece of info is how the `gpg` tool converts a passphrase into the cipherkey, which for AES256 has to be precisely 256-bit (hence the name). I doubt a phassphrase is going to have 256 bits of entropy so in this sense, using AES256 with a passphrase is nasty security theater you need to stop (AES256 makes people go: Oooh, 256 bit, nice! but you don't have that at all; AES128 is strictly better here, it sends the better message).

Comment: Once you have determined how `PASSWORD` is turned into 256 bits, from there the task is mostly trivial; the one extra thing you need to know is the 'mode'. Is it CBC, GCM, etc. For some modes you need a padding algorithm but virtually everybody uses PKCS5Padding. If you know "passphrase to cipherkey algorithm", and "mode", then you can write it in java.

Comment: A quick check on the GPG docs seem to indicate none of this stuff is written down anywhere, which means `gpg`'s input and output is a black hole as far as the docs is concerned: Proprietary. Fortunately, gpg is open source. Your task is to dive into the source and figure out the answers to my 2 questions. Or find docs I wasn't able to.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into those questions and provide some example code when I get so far.

Comment: gpg will encrypt it using public/private key. The only place passphrases arise in gpg is to access said private keys

Comment: @g00se I find various references in the docs that the `--symmetric` option will "This command asks for a passphrase" which suggests you're incorrect.

Comment: It's possible that `--cipher-algo` means: "Encrypt/decrypt in the usual fashion: Generate a random symmetric encryption key, encrypt the data with this, then encrypt this key with a public key or private key as normal - just, for the symmetric part, use this algo". Docs are unclear.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, it would seem that gpg *can* do symmetric encryption but I'm not quite sure why an app/API for PKI encryption would be used for this purpose, irrespective of the lack of "good examples" using Bouncy, etc. It would be better to use proper PKI

Comment: gpg is a toolbox to do all sorts of crypto stuff. The docs are unfortunately highly nebulous about the specific steps and algorithms used; probably intentionally, in the sense that your average tech savvy user doesn't really know which chain of crypto operations is safe and which isn't, and you can't easily test either. Doing symmetric crypto is part of the tools in the box.

Comment: There are reasons for wanting only symmetric encryption. It's dangerous to walk off of the beaten path here of course (again, an error in your understanding of the process means your stuff is now insecure, and you won't know and can't easily test until it is too late) - I agree, @DarienBowen should consider their ideas on whatever process involves "I want symmetric crypto here" carefully.

Comment: @rzwitserloot: gpg implements exactly the algorithms and formats defined in RFC4880 (plus some additions and extensions not relevant here), and so does bcpg. That's the _point_ of having a standard -- there is _one_ specification and all the implementations implement it (or at least sufficient parts of it) so that they can interoperate. `gpg --symmetric` does packet type 3 which _does_ use PBE and NOT publickey. And although `gpg` has quite a few options, it isn't really a 'toolbox'; `libgcrypt` (which it uses internally) is.

Comment: *And then I try to decrypt the resulting file with GPG.* How, and with what result?

Comment: I am decrypting with the command specified at the start of the post, and the result is `gpg: [don't know]: 1st length byte missing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right on the edge of it. If you look at the whole directory https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples you see there are:

- `KeyBasedFileProcessor` -- for the encrypt side, does:

  1. read the (whole) input file and create compressed-literal-data packet in memory
  2. create `PGPEncryptedDataGenerator` and give it a public-key encryption 'method' (for a selected key)
  3. open a stream on the generator and write the compressed-literal-data packet to it (which results in it being encrypted and written to the output file)
- `KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor` -- ditto:

  1. *don't* read the whole input
  2. create the same generator as for non-Large
  3. open a stream on the generator
  4. use `PGPCompressedDataGenerator` to open a compressed-data stream on 3
  5. (in `PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData`) use `PGPLiteralDataGenerator` to open a literal-data stream on 4, and then copy from the input file to that stream, which results in it being put into PGP's literal-data format, compressed *and* encrypted and written to the output file)
- `PBEFileProcessor` -- for encrypt is exactly the same as `KeyBased` except that it uses a method for PBE (with the given passphrase) instead of one for public-key encryption

Now, what do you think would happen if you make the same changes to `PBEFileProcessor` as the `KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor` made to `KeyBasedFileProcessor`? Might you have a `PBELargeFileProcessor` that does password-based encryption of large files -- or with the obvious changes, anything you can access and read as an `InputStream`?

Except that (all) the examples use CAST5; you want to change that to AES_256 (or whatever else).

Comment: Thank you! This did help me get further, but I still have problems. I updated the original post.

Comment: Darien: yes you must close each level, in the reverse of the order opened -- as the BC example does. Since you left out compression, that means `outputStream.close()` for the literaldata then `cout.close()` for the encrypteddata and `encryptedOutputStream.close()` for the armor -- both of which are currently lost when method `encrypt()` returns, maybe make them fields of your `PGPEncrypter` object? -- and finally `fileOutputStream.close()` in your calling code.

Comment: That did the trick. I had forgotten to close the original OutputStream. I will update the original post with the changes.